# issue with shibboleth SP in docker container behind proxy

Tags: php, docker, apache2, docker-compose, shibboleth

I am trying to get a shibboleth set up working in a docker container behind a proxy.

Currently I am able to get redirected to the shibboleth idp page where I can enter my login details and shibboleth will authenticate me. It is failing with a 404 when it attempts to redirect back to: https://my-service.org/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

I can't tell if this is an apache issue or something with the shibboleth config.

There is a server with apache and docker running on it. The apache here is proxying traffic to the docker containers running on the same server. I have dns point a domain name to the proxy. Lets call it "my-service.org". The apache proxy config for my-service.org is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my-service.org
        ServerAdmin devs@blah.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-service

        Redirect permanent / https://my-service.org/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName my-service.org
        ServerAdmin devs@blah.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-service

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/docker-dev/my-service.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/docker-dev/my-service_ssl_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/blah.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/ssl/private/blah.key
        SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCompression off
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-SSL expr=%{HTTPS}
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8088/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8088/       
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The 'my-service' container is based on the 'php:7-apache-buster' container and is running apache with shibd. It is part of a docker-compose stack. The apache config of the container is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@blah.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-service

  <Directory /var/www/html/my-service/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location "/shibboleth_login.php">
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibUseHeaders On
    require valid-user
  </Location>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Like I said everything is working up until the point of redirection back from the shibboleth idp to the SP, where it 404s. The logs are not telling me much but there is an error log when I load the containers apache config:

`AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.6. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

I am not sure if this would have an affect of the situation.

One thing I thought may have an affect is the fact that I have shibboleth set to handle SSL:

```
<Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem"
                  checkAddress="false" handlerSSL="true" cookieProps="https">
```

But my container apache config only defines a HTTP virtual host block. As you can see the proxy passes the protocol to the container via the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-SSL` headers. I needed those for the 'my-service' php app but not sure if they have an affect on shibboleth. The initial interaction with the idp works fine, its just the redirection back that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to add a `ServerName` attribute as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@blah.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-service

  ServerName https://my-service.org:443
  UseCanonicalName On

  <Directory /var/www/html/my-service/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location "/shibboleth_login.php">
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibUseHeaders On
    require valid-user
  </Location>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```